# Cordova Cannot save files inside root folder

Tags: android, angular, cordova, frontend, cordova-plugins

I'm trying in several ways to try to save in the Download folder on the root of the android device, but I can never access it and the file is never created, not even if I create a directory, the directory is not created. One way I thought to get around this would be to use the cordova to move the created file to the Download folder, however it doesn't work either.
The cordova documentation asks to use `LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT` , but I still can't access the root of the system. Even though I manually type the local :`file:///storage/emulated/0/`,I still can't access and generate any files.

Current code that saves in to `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic/files/`:

```
        function savePDF(fileName, fileData) {
          window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory , function (dir) {
            // dir.getDirectory('images', { create: true }, function (subDirEntry) {});
            dir.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
              fileEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {
                writer.onwrite = function (evt) {
                  Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    text: `${fileName} foi salvo na pasta ${cordova.file.externalDataDirectory}`,
                    showConfirmButton: true
                  });
                };
                writer.write(fileData);
              })

            }, function () {
              Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                text: `Houve algum erro ao gerar o pdf , tente novamente`,
                showConfirmButton: true
              });
            });
          });
        }
```

and in the config.xml the preferences to access are set for several folders:

```
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,assets,root" />
```

Comment: `I manually type the local :file:///storage/emulated/0/,I still can't access and generate any files.` That is no file path but a path to root of external storage. You cannot create files or folders there on an Android 11 device but you can in `/storage/emulated/0/Download` or in `/storage/emulated/0/Documents` on more of such public dirs.

Comment: In the manifest file and at runtine you should ask for storage permissions.

Comment: I already put the storage permissions and my first try was to add files in download folder , but still not working. what I try to do is type where is `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory` i change to `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download`, but still can't add my file there.